# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key'

Tags: c#, linq

I am currently getting error in my grouping logic. I am trying to sum the values in EMV for  productnames that are same. I am getting error while passing only some list. How do I avoid this exception. I am not aware of doing null checks in linq experssion

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key'
```

Code

```
public Dictionary<string, decimal> SumProductEmv(IEnumerable<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel> allProducts)
{
    if (allProducts == null)
        return null;

    return allProducts
        .GroupBy(product => product.ProductName)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            ProductName = group.Key, // this is the value you grouped on - the ProductName
            EmvSum = group.Sum(item => item.Emv)
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.ProductName, x => x.EmvSum);
}
```

Comment: Presumably `ProductName` is null. I'd imagine a `.Where` before the group by would solve that.

Answer (score 7):

You could filter `null` or empty keys out using `Where`, try this:

```
return allProducts
    .Where(product => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.ProductName))
    .GroupBy(product => product.ProductName)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        ProductName = group.Key, // this is the value you grouped on - the ProductName
        EmvSum = group.Sum(item => item.Emv)
    })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.ProductName, x => x.EmvSum);
```

---

Also, you could `Distinct()` to prevent *ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary* but then you need to decide which element you want to take, first, last, etc.